# How to replace googleSignIn icon ?(flutter)

Tags: flutter-layout, google-signin

##### I tried to find a way but couldn't find it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbylf.png)

Comment: Provide more details to your question such that the users understand where you have faced issue in which type of situation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want replace googleSignin  Screen icon ,  
The red frame of the photo